# Gaussian distribution with poisson variance

Tags: normal-distribution, poisson-distribution, gaussian-mixture-distribution

Let's $r_t\sim \mathcal{N}(0,V_t)$ where $V_t = (1+m)^{J_t}$, $m\geq0$ and $J_t\sim \mathcal{P}oi(\lambda)$. How can we compute the distribution of $r_t$ when the parameters are $m$ and $\lambda$. In other words I would like to compute $$\sum_{j\geq0}\frac{e^\lambda}{j!}\lambda^j\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi(1+m)^{j}}}\exp\left\{-\frac{r_t^2}{2(1+m)^{j}}\right\}\,.$$

I know this sum is convergent as for all $j$, $\exp\left\{-\frac{r_t^2}{2(1+m)^{j}}\right\}\leq 1$ then $$\sum_{j\geq0}\frac{e^\lambda}{j!}\lambda^j\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi(1+m)^{j}}}\exp\left\{-\frac{r_t^2}{2(1+m)^{j}}\right\} \leq \sum_{j\geq0}\frac{e^\lambda}{j!}\lambda^j\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi(1+m)^{j}}} = \frac{\exp\left\{\lambda+\lambda(1+m)^{-1/2}\right\}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\,.$$

My objective at the end will be to estimate this model by MCMC. So, I would like to sample parameters $m$ and $\lambda$ after computing their posterior. An accepted answer should then help me to compute those posteriors.

Thanks

Comment: Could you give us a hint concerning what an acceptable answer might look like?  What property of this distribution do you want to compute or exhibit or analyze?

Comment: What exactly are you missing to plug it in MCMC?

Comment: @Tim: If I can not compute this, all the posterior with be represented like a serie and in my Gibbs sample, I will be obliged to use Metropolis Hasting to sample each parameter. The computation of each distribution will take time and then the Gibbs sampler will be too heavy.

Comment: With only two parameters and what is effectively a closed-form solution (as you can truncate the $J_t$ at some value based on the current estimate of $\lambda$, e.g., the $99.999^{th}$ percentile of the Poisson dist'n), it seems to me you can just find the MLE directly through optimization, without use of MCMC.

Comment: @jbowman: Thanks for you comment. In fact, the model is more complicate than that and have about twenty parameters. I am obliged to estimate it by MCMC as I am using Indian Buffet Process estimation.

Comment: I see little hope of simplifying this symbolically. But perhaps you can organize the computations so that only one of $\lambda$ and $m$ changes at one time. If $\lambda$ is temporarily fixed, you can compute the sum on a grid of $m$’s and $r$’s, and then approximate the function elsewhere by interpolating between the values on the grid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $J_t$ has support on the non-negative integers, you have a [Gaussian mixture model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_model#Gaussian_mixture_model), with marginalised sampling density:

$$p_{R_t}(r | \lambda,m) 
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{1}{j!} \Big( \frac{\lambda}{\sqrt{1+m}} \Big)^j \exp \bigg( - \frac{r^2}{2(1+m)^j} - \lambda \bigg).$$

This distribution is non-trivial, but we know it is symmetric around zero (and therefore has zero mean and zero skewness).  Using the [law of iterated variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance) its variance is:

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{V}(R_t | \lambda, m)
&= \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{V}( R_t |J_t)] + \mathbb{V}[\mathbb{E}( R_t |J_t)] \\[6pt]
&= \mathbb{E}[(1+m)^{J_t}] + \mathbb{V}[0] \\[6pt]
&= G_{J_t}(1+m) \\[6pt]
&= \exp(\lambda m). \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

(In this working $G_{J_t}$ denotes the [probability generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability-generating_function) of $J_t$.)  It is also simple to establish the marginal kurtosis.  As a preliminary step we have:

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}(R_t^4 | \lambda, m)
&= \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{\lambda^j e^{-\lambda}}{j!} \cdot \mathbb{E}(R_t^4 | J_t) \\[6pt]
&= \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{\lambda^j e^{-\lambda}}{j!} \cdot \frac{3}{(1+m)^{2j}} \\[6pt]
&= 3 e^{-\lambda} \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{1}{j!} \cdot \Big( \frac{\lambda}{(1+m)^2} \Big)^j \\[6pt]
&= 3 \exp({-\lambda}) \exp({\lambda/(1+m)^2}) \\[6pt]
&= 3 \exp \Bigg( - \lambda \cdot \frac{2m + m^2}{(1+m)^2} \Bigg). \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

We therefore have the marginal kurtosis

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{Kurt}(R_t | \lambda, m)
&= \frac{\mathbb{E}(R_t^4 | \lambda, m)}{\mathbb{V}(R_t^4 | \lambda, m)^2}. \\[6pt]
&= 3 \exp \Bigg( - \lambda \cdot \frac{2m + m^2}{(1+m)^2} \Bigg) \exp(-2 \lambda m) \\[6pt]
&= 3 \exp \Bigg( - \lambda \cdot \frac{4m + 5m^2 + 2 m^3}{(1+m)^2} \Bigg). \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

Given that the this Gaussian mixture is symmetric with a known variance and kurtosis, you could approximate it well by a [generalised error distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_normal_distribution) with appropriate choice of parameters using the method of moments using the above marginal variance and kurtosis.  This would give you a substantially simplified approximation to your problem.  In any case, your MCMC simulations of the posterior will depend on the prior distribution you use for $\lambda$ and $m$, which you have not specified here.

Comment: As It seems to not have a closed form, and it can be approximate by a generalized error distribution, maybe, I will just try using directly a generalized error distribution instead of a mixture gaussian. Thank you very much.